# how to move the turtles together free neighbors without other turtles occupy them

Tags: netlogo

I want to move turtles with a "security distance" from other turtles, for example one patch.
this is my code:

```
ask turtles [
       let q neighbors with [
         (not any? turtles-here) and (not any? other turtles-on neighbors) 
       ]
       if any? q [
         face one-of q 
         move-to patch-ahead 1
         ]
      ]
    if any? turtles-on neighbors [   ?????   ]
```

the start condition is each turtles not have turtles-on neighbors.
Also i wish turtles find a new patch to go if turtles-on q or any turtles-on q neighbors, but i have no idea..

i try also this:

to move

```
ask turtles [
   set ahead patches at-points [[2 1] [2 0] [2 -1]]
   set neighbors-e patch-at 1 0 
     ask turtles with [not any? turtles-on ahead] [
       let d distance exit                          ;exit is patch "target"
       if (distance [exit] of neighbors-e < d) [
         fd 1
       ]
     ]
   ]
```

end

but it shows the error : `A patch can't access a turtle variable without specifying which turtle. (refer to neighbors-e)`

The idea is:

1. look 3 patches ahead at distance 2
2. if any? turtles-on this
3. control if the distance of exit where you will go (neighbors-e) is lesser than actual position (to verify if direction to exit is correctly)
4. fd 1

Comment: obviously the code doesn't run..

Comment: closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24516240/86485

Comment: I would like to help, but your description of what you're trying to do is difficult to follow — especially your description of step 3, which seems like the crucial step. I'm not able to guess what the intent is behind the code you've written.

Comment: You may be trying to learn too much all at once by writing a complex procedure all at once. This might help: write a much simpler version ; get it working; attempt to make a very small improvement to it, and get that working; and so on. If at any point you get stuck, come here, show your code, and ask a specific question about it.