# how to create a list of neighbors to verify if occupied or not by other turtles

Tags: netlogo

i wont to know what neighbors are occupied from other turtles, in general terms i wont to know  what patches are occupied in-radius from the turtles patch. Better if i can create a list of them or similar to verify what of this are occupied or no. Some suggestion?
thanks

Comment: how is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/q/24514369/86485?

Comment: it's no so different, this is probably the answer at last condition on other question..

Answer (score 1):

For the 8 neighboring patches: `neighbors with [ any? turtles-here ]`

For patches in a radius: `patches in-radius x with [ any? turtles-here ]`